# Removing Version Numbers with Regular Expression

Tags: python-2.7

I want to replace the version number in a string, e.g.,

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148 9.0.30729.4148
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161 9.0.30729.6161
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64 1.0.0
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86 1.0.0
Windows UPnP Browser 0.1.01
CamStudio
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148 9.0.30729.4148
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161 9.0.30729.6161
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64 1.0.0
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86 1.0.0
```

I want it to become

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64 
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86 
Windows UPnP Browser
CamStudioe 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64 
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86
```

Following is my code

```
s="MicrosoftVisualC++2008Redistributable-x86\nMicrosoftVisualC++2008Redistributable-x86\nMicrosoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64\nMicrosoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86\nWindowsUPnPBrowser\nCamStudioe\nMicrosoftVisualC++2008Redistributable-x86\nMicrosoftVisualC++2008Redistributable-x86\nMicrosoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64\nMicrosoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86"
s1=s.replace('\r','').split('\n')
s2=[]
for s in s1:
    m = re.search('(?<=([ ]+[\.\d]*)*$)', s)
    s2.append(m.group(0))
print(s2)
```

I get the problem

```
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Is there a better way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that you can have things in the pattern that aren't returned in a match group (i.e., they will be part of group(0), but not any other group).
Here is what I worked out:

```
# put the lines to clean in a string
s='''Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148 9.0.30729.4148
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161 9.0.30729.6161
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64 1.0.0
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86 1.0.0
Windows UPnP Browser 0.1.01
CamStudio
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148 9.0.30729.4148
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161 9.0.30729.6161
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64 1.0.0
Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86 1.0.0'''

# use findall to return the parts we want
print(re.findall(r'(.+?)(?: (?:[\d\.]+))*(?:\n|\Z)', s))
```

Explanation of the regex:  `(.+?)` is a non-greedy capture of a bunch of characters.
`(?: [\d\.]+)*` is a non-capturing group, repeated zero or more times, that starts with a space and has only digits or '.' following (in each repeat).
`(?:\n|\Z)` matches a newline or the end of the string.  If your string might have carriage returns, you could use `\r?(?:\n|\Z)` instead.

For a regex that has only one capturing group, `re.findall` returns group(1) of each match in the string, which is exactly what you want. The other parts of the regex must be matched, but since they are not captured, they will not be returned.

Comment: This approach miss the last one Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86

Comment: `[\n\Z]` doesn't work, because `\Z` will match `Z` when in a character class. You can use `(?:\n|\Z)` instead.

Comment: You are both correct.  Changing `[\n\Z]` to `(?:\n|\Z)`  catches the last one.