# Regarding \Z in regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Why this returns me [ABC]

```
s='''ABC'''
# use findall to return the parts we want
print(re.findall(r'ABC\Z', s))
```

While this returns me nothing?

```
s='''ABC'''
# use findall to return the parts we want
print(re.findall(r'ABC[\Z]', s))
```

Comment: `\Z` matches a location, not a character, so it just means `[Z]` in a character class. Think of it like `\b`

Comment: @4castle Actually I am facing a problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570062/removing-version-numbers-with-regular-expression
where I can't use [\Z\n], do you have any opinion on that?

Comment: @4castle the solution there will miss the last line exactly because of it is using \Z

Comment: @4castle, thanks for here and for the other question
, if you could post as answer, i would be able to accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

## Root cause

When an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) or [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) are placed into a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) they lose their special meaning. Acc. to the [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `[]`
>          Used to indicate a set of characters.

and

> `\b` 
>          ... Inside a character range, `\b` represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

`\Z` behaves the same way as `\b`: inside a character class, the anchor meaning is lost. Note that `r'\Z'` does not produces any warning in Python versions before 3.6 and matches a single `Z` because it is an [unknown escape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for Python re:

> Unknown escapes such as `\j` are left alone.

Starting with Python 3.6, you cannot use a `\` with an ASCII letter after it that is an unknown escape (see [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)):

> *Changed in version 3.6*: Unknown escapes consisting of `'\'` and an ASCII letter now are errors.

So, `r'[\Z]'` in Python up to 3.5 will work as follows:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'[\Z]', '\\Z')) # => ['Z']
```

## Solution

To match either a (string of) letter(s) *or* a zero-width assertion, use a [*grouping* construct](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), capturing `(...)` or non-capturing `(?:...)`,  with an [*alternation* operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`:

```
(?:\n|\Z)
```

This will match either a newline symbol, or the very end of string (in Python, `\Z` matches the same position in string as `\z` in PCRE/Perl/.NET).

Answer (score 0):

```
s='''ABC'''
# use findall to return the parts we want
print(re.findall(r'ABC[\Z]', s))

error: bad escape \Z at position 4
```

this code will return an error.

There are some rules about character class:

- Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets. For example, `[(+*)]` will match any of the literal characters `'(', '+', '*', or ')'`.

what happened in the character class is: regex engine trying to escape the letter `Z`. Since the `Z` is not special characters in regex, the engine will return an error.